# UI rolled up when keyboard appears - MAUI

Tags: c#, maui

It is my definition for xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Entry Placeholder="Write text..."/>
    <Button Text="Button" Grid.Row="1" VerticalOptions="End" />
</Grid>
```

When I click on control Entry and keyboard is visable. My interface is rolled up:

[image]

I can fix it by remove all stars from RowDecinition Height but setting the value rigidly causes that it does not adapt to all screens.

Is it possible to turn off roll up interface when keyboard is visable?

Comment: you could try to set the height of the grid to screenheight (from Microsoft.Maui.Devices.DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo) during initialisation

Comment: The stars mean that all the available space is allocated to a row's height. When multiple rows use the star for their height, the available space is distributed accordingly, in your case that's evenly. Now, with the keyboard open, the available space gets smaller. Do you want the keyboard to overlay your UI? Keep in mind that some input fields may be covered and not usable then.

Comment: Long discussion of related problems in [issue iOS Keyboard covers the entry](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/4792). If you wrap your layout in a ScrollView, it will stop "rolling up". Or use Bacon's suggestion. Hopefully soon, "AutoResize" and "AutoPan" options will be added. AutoPan will be what you want; then an entry in lower-half of screen would slide form up to not be covered.

Comment: @Bacon I tried and it's not work in the same way for all screens

Comment: @ewerspej Yes, I want my keyboard to overlap the interface.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve this discussion is about something different. Because they expect entry will always visible. But I want to that my interface does not change position

Comment: I know. They have the *opposite* problem, because they wrap in ScrollView. That is causing the layout NOT to adjust, which is what you want. Therefore, you can wrap in ScrollView. (In the future, you can have it work regardless of whether entry is near top or near bottom. But that option does not exist yet.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to set the  `Application.WindowSoftInputModeAdjust` attached property to `Pan`.

Please refer to the following code:

```xml
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8" ?> 
<Application xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiApp"                 
             xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maui.Controls.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Microsoft.Maui.Controls"
             android:Application.WindowSoftInputModeAdjust="Pan"
             x:Class="MauiApp0207.App">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/Styles.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

For more information,you can check [Soft keyboard input mode on Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/android/platform-specifics/soft-keyboard-input-mode?view=net-maui-7.0).

**Update**

In IOS, you can try to obtain keyboard's frame via `UIKeyboard.FrameEndUserInfoKey` and calculate the height that need to change.

```
NSValue result = (NSValue)args.Notification.UserInfo.ObjectForKey(new NSString(UIKeyboard.FrameEndUserInfoKey));

CGSize keyboardSize = result.RectangleFValue.Size;

private void Entry_Focused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
{
    if (DeviceInfo.Current.Platform == DevicePlatform.iOS)
    {
       NFloat bottom;
        try
        {
             UIWindow window = UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate.GetWindow();
                bottom = window.SafeAreaInsets.Bottom;
        }
        catch
        {
             bottom = 0;
        }
        var heightChange = (keyboardSize.Height - bottom);
        layout.TranslateTo(0, originalTranslationY.Value - heightChange, 50);
    }
}

private void Entry_Unfocused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
{
    if (DeviceInfo.Current.Platform == DevicePlatform.iOS)
    {
        layout.TranslateTo(0, 0, 50);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: This only works for Android.

Comment: But I don't want my interface to move, the keyboard should be superimposed on the interface and not interfere with its arrangement.

Comment: Hi @SilnyToJa, setting `android:Application.WindowSoftInputModeAdjust="Pan"` will not make the UI move, you can try it. And I have updated the answer, you can check it.

Comment: I set this setting 10 times, tested on the emulator and on the phone, only after deleting the bin, obj, delate and reinstalling on the phone it works fine. Thanks

Comment: For me, I had to use android:Application.WindowSoftInputModeAdjust="Resize"

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT where does `originalTranslationY.Value` and `args.Notification` come from? They are undefined in your example.

Answer (score 2):

in MainActivity.cs:

```cs
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    //...
 
    App.Current.On<Microsoft.Maui.Controls.PlatformConfiguration.Android>().UseWindowSoftInputModeAdjust(WindowSoftInputModeAdjust.Pan);

    //...
}
```